# UI Tab Bar Controller not displaying all tabs on device. Simulator works perfectly

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, xcode5

I have a Tab Bar Controller created with Storyboard (iPad app).  With 7 tabs at the bottom the app worked perfectly.  I added an 8th tab and tested it with no issues on the simulator, but when I run it on an actual iPad the 8th tab doesn't appear.  If I add a 9th tab, the simulator places the "more" tab as expected, but again on the device nothing.

I am using XCode 5.0 and iOS7.

Has anyone run into this problem?  I haven't been able to turn anything up with Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two responses helped me to figure this one out.  To allow for persistence when the user reordered the tabs I was making use of iCloud.  What was happening was that I was restoring the old tabs (and order) from the cloud which was overwriting my storyboard changes.  Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a clean build and/or deleting you app form the simulator. I've found I sometimes have more than one version installed in the simulator if I changed the app id or something and Xcode can den confused and launch the wrong one in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Go to the MainWindow.xib, select the Window object and check the "Full Screen at Launch".